# Area under the curve using recursive

Tags: c++, function, recursion

So I was given a program to create that involves reading an external file which outputs an image similar to an x-y field I was able to produce this much so for but I am stuck at a dead end... I removed the # so the libraries could be read

The data file contains

```
x values    y values
20.00       0
20.02       15
20.04       27
20.06       39
20.08       54
20.10       65
20.12       75
20.14       84
20.16       93
20.18       101
20.20       108
20.22       113
20.24       116
20.26       115
20.28       112
20.30       107
20.32       100
20.34       92
20.36       83
20.38       74
20.40       64
20.42       53
20.44       39
20.46       27
20.48       15
20.50       0
```

---

```
/* This program reads numbers from a file. */
#include< iostream >
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
     int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    //Open the File.

   inFile.open("xydata.txt");

   //Read the numbers from the file

    inFile >> x1;  //x1 =20
    inFile >> y1;   // y1 = 0
    inFile >> x2;   // x2 =20.02
    inFile >> y2; //y2 = 15

    //Close File.
    inFile.close();




//Calculate the total Area underneath the curve


    double h, b, a, trap, final_trap;
    a = (x2 - x1);
    b = (y2 - y1);
    trap = ((a+b)/2);
    final_trap = trap*b;


    cout<<final_trap<<endl ;

    return 0;
}



/*

// Writing data into a File
int main()
{
ofstream outputFile
outputFile.open("xydata.dat")

cout << "Now writing data into the file" <<endl;

//Writing Area into the file
outputFile <<

//close this file
outputFile.close();
cout << "Done." << endl;
return 0;

*/
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are trying to read integers but your file contains real numbers. **ADD:** You need to check that you read in the values correctly by checking the stream flags.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the whole program (but reading from stdin - I'm sure you can fix that):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  bool first_iteration = true;
  float area = 0.0; 
  float ox, oy, x, y;
  while (cin>>x && cin>>y) {
    if (!first_iteration) 
      area += (x-ox) * (y+oy)/2.0;
    ox=x; oy=y;
    first_iteration=false;
  }
  cout << "Area is " << area << endl;
}
```

If you really do have those column labels in the input file you'll have to eat them at the outset.